# Dynamically generated route-href throws error

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to dynamically generate a `route-href` in a list of items. I basically have this:

```
this.items = [
    {
        name: 'Foo',
        route: 'item',
        routeParams: {
            id: 1
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Bar',
        route: 'item',
        routeParams: {
            id: 2
        }
    }
];
```

And in my view:

```
<ul>
    <li repeat.for="item of items">
        <a route-href="route: ${item.route}; params.bind: ${item.routeParams}">
            ${item.name}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But Aurelia tells me:

```
aurelia-logging-console.js:54 ERROR [route-href] Error: A route with name 'undefined' could not be found. Check that `name: 'undefined'` was specified in the route's config
```

If I print the `${item.route}` and `${item.routeParams}` they do contain the correct values:

```
<ul>
    <li repeat.for="item of items">
        <a route-href="route: ${item.route}; params.bind: ${item.routeParams}">
            ${item.name} ${item.route} ${item.routeParams}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Why? :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
<a route-href="route.bind: item.route; params.bind: item.routeParams">...</a>
```

More information at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7

Comment: Thanks :) `params.bind=${item.routeParams}` was a typo, I had `params.bind: ${item.routeParams}` in my code. `route.bind` was missing though and solved it.